# pageX and pageY are always set to 0 in Firefox during the ondrag event

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing a visual editor where users are allowed to drag images onto the page, and drag other images inside these previously dragged images (kind of 'add another image').

I basically only need the mouse coordinates during the drag: the element hiliting etc... I do with custom functions based on these coordinates.

The problem is, while on Webkit I can get them with `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`, under Firefox (v.16.0.1 OSX) their 'counterparts' `pageX` and `pageY` are always zero in my experience during a drag.

However, they are not zero during `mouseMove`.

Smart as I am, I did a

```js
$(document).on("mouseMove",function(e){__PX=e.pageX,__PY=e.pageY});
```

to always have the latest `pageX` and `pageY` so I could use them inside the `onDrag` handler but...

the `OnMouseMove` does not fire during a Drag And Drop operation :( :(

Is there any way I can get the Mouse X and Y during a DnD? I'd like not to clutter my code too much, as it already works on different platforms but not on Firefox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is event.clientX incorrectly showing as 0 in firefox for dragend event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656061/why-is-event-clientx-incorrectly-showing-as-0-in-firefox-for-dragend-event)

Answer (score 9):

I found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887316/how-do-i-get-clientx-and-clienty-to-work-inside-my-drag-event-handler-on-firef?rq=1).

I've solved it like this:

```js
(___NODRAGEVENT = $.browser.mozilla) && $(document).on("dragover", function(e) {
    e = e.originalEvent;
    ___PAGEX = e.clientX || e.pageX;
    ___PAGEY = e.clientY || e.pageY;
});
```

I'm really surprised and confused that `onDragOver` does include `clientX` and `clientY`. Why don't they populate them on the drag event?

Comment: lol omg this makes total sense, WHY didn't they include this in ondrag!

Comment: wow the answer was from 5 years ago! i am surprised this is still needed

Comment: I guess a lot of already built solutions account for this, but dnd from scratch still has this issue in firefox and of course our good ol' friend IE 11.

Comment: Absolutely ridiculous that in 2018 Firefox makes people still resort to workarounds like this. Thanks for posting your solution though.

Comment: This answer is still valid in 2021 and nothing is changed by Firefox team

Comment: Still valid on 2022, and for `drag`.

Comment: How can we add this script to React?