# Javascript function does not work in firefox but does in chrome, safari, IE and edge

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Could anyone tell me why this function won't execute in Firefox. The rest of the Javascript functions throughout the file work successfully except for this one (it flat out won't execute, no errors in the console). I suspected it was the `pageX` property, however that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
var prevX = 0;
var i = 0;
var drgleft = 0;
var drgright = 0;


function sequence_1(event){
    if(prevX == 0){
        prevX = event.pageX;
        return false;
    }  
    //drag left
    if(prevX > event.pageX){
        console.log('dragged left');
        drgleft++;
        if(drgleft == 2){
            drgleft = 0;
            i--;
            if(i < 0){
                i = 30; //for optimization reasons, input the cache.length value manually (this avoids unnecessary errors in the console and laggy framerate as a result).
            } 
            document.getElementById("TheBigOne").src = cache[i].src; //use console.log(i); as a method of verifying that the code is executing correctly
        }
    }
    else if(prevX < event.pageX){
        console.log('dragged right');
        drgright++;
        if(drgright == 2){
            drgright = 0;
            i++;
            if(i > 30){ //for optimization reasons, input the cache.length value manually (this avoids unnecessary errors in the console and laggy framerate as a result).
                i=0;
            }
            document.getElementById("TheBigOne").src = cache[i].src;
        }
    }
    else{
    }
    prevX = event.pageX
}
```

### EDIT:

In my first post I didn't include the relevent HTML code that calls the function, for that I apologise and will implement it below.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>
          <div class="The_main_event" draggable = "true" ondrag="sequence_1(event)" id = "GD">

              <img src="file:///C:/Users/Harry/Desktop/Website/Web_aeroplane/Web%20Test.0031.png" id="TheBigOne">

           </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What calls this function? What type of event is `event`? It'd be helpful if you could condense your problem into a single, self-contained HTML page that works on all the browsers but Firefox.

Comment: it's interesting to note that firefox is the only browser without the internet explorer kludge global  `event` object - not that that should be an issue in this code, but, you never know

Comment: It's apparently an event handler. Please post the code where you attach that event handler. The problem is probably there.

Comment: @JaromandaX the `event` variable here isn't the global `event` you're talking about. It's the argument of the function so it's defined.

Comment: I know, just an interesting observation, and depending on how the function is invoked, may end up being more than just an observation - without seeing how this function is tied to some event, it's just speculative on my part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a UIEvent, or a MouseEvent?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/pageX

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX

UIEvents aren't standard and the documentation linked above has Firefox as unknown compatibility.

I'm guessing when you say it won't run, you mean, it's not working how you expect it to. It looks like in your case it is either returning false, or is doing nothing except trying to update `prevX`. If `event.pageX` is `undefined` and therefore `prevX` is `undefined`, it would cause your function to have no effect and appear to not run.

EDIT:
After seeing your update, it looks like it's because the event you're listening to doesn't have pageX. See here for documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag

This may also help [FireFox onDrag Pagex PageY always zero ;(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110349/firefox-ondrag-pagex-pagey-always-zero)

Comment: I tried that, changing the      pageX       to       screenX  however that hasn't appeared to work. I did inspect the code thought, it appears each time the drag event is fired, it returns false (indicating that prevX doesn't change on drag).

Comment: The onDrag zero seems to be the same issue, I put a console.log(prevX); statement at the first if statement, and it always returns zero.

Answer (score 1):

Open Firefox's debugger (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on Windows) set a breakpoint at the *first line* of the function body. The contents of `event` will be inspectable. You can step through the function (<kbd>F10</kbd> in Windows) to see what's happening. If the event is not directly from mouse/touch, it may not have a `pageX` property, therefore have no effects.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported by firefox Browser and W3C. Other browsers ignore this specification and use `Mousemove` instead, to address this specific issue. However you can use `ondragstart` and `ondragend` to get the co-ordinates of the specific event.

Comment: Hi Santosh, yeah I found the same issue on a forum post from 2009, I'm surprised they haven't fixed it yet. I added an ondragover event listener at the document level to fix the issue, now it works perfectly. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi @Mr_incompetent, The bug is still open < https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521 >. Hope it gets fixed soon. please mark this as answer if it helped.