# No e.clientX or e.clientY on drag event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, drag-and-drop

I've implemented a simple drag and drop system using directives in Angular. It works fine in Chrome, but **Firefox** doesn't expose `event.clientX`, `event.clientY` properties on drag event (They just refuse to fix it).

So I'm looking for a good alternative to expose these properties on drag event: the x,y coordinates are needed for visual feedback on drag event.

Code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ApeyQ4FcdsA8Ez18Roi0?p=preview) - check out in Chrome and **Firefox** to see the problem.

In Chrome, drag an item in the folders, you'll have the same item displayed as visual feedback following the mouse, not in Firefox (because **Firefox** doesn't support `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` in the drag event).

the problem is here (beginning line 45):

```
.on('drag', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.clientX) {
        el.css({
           'top': e.originalEvent.clientY + 10,
           'left': e.originalEvent.clientX + 10
        });
    } else {
        el.css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

So how can I get the mouse position on screen during a drag event, in Firefox (the angular way, I mean with directives, no global variable, or whatever)?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is event.clientX incorrectly showing as 0 in firefox for dragend event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656061/why-is-event-clientx-incorrectly-showing-as-0-in-firefox-for-dragend-event)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can hook up to `dragover` on `document` -- `clientX` and `clientY` are exposed there.
Use functional closure to not populating global scope. Here is updated [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/73lbtvLDrrYb57Om4jn6?p=preview) (tested in Chrome and FF).

Changes to js:

```
.directive('mpDrag', function($timeout, $window, $document) {

    // keeping coordinates private and 
    // shared among all instances of the directive
    var mouseX, mouseY;

    $document.on("dragover", function(event){
      mouseX = event.originalEvent.clientX;
      mouseY = event.originalEvent.clientY;
    })

    return {
      ...
      link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        ...
        $timeout(function() {

        ...
            .on('drag', function(e) {
              // just use mouseX, mouseY directely here
              // (btw. you should detect differently when to hide the element)
              console.log(mouseX, mouseY); 
              if (e.originalEvent.clientX) {
                el.css({
                  'top': mouseY,
                  'left': mouseX
                });
              } else {
                el.css('display', 'none');
              }
            });
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

Comment: Anyway to do this on Typescript and React?

Answer (score 9):

You must borrow drag coordinates from the document itself:

```
var dragX = 0,
    dragY = 0;

element.on('dragstart', function(e) {
    document.ondragover = function(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        dragX = event.pageX,
        dragY = event.pageY;
    };
});

element.on('drag', function(e) {
    el.css({
        'top': dragY + 10,
        'left': dragX + 10
    });
});
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kA58c7Q0vCMpjBfQ1znV?p=preview)